# Tabular environment misalignment with the section title

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

Why do I have this misalignment of the table respect to the section title? How can I get rid of it?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}
\section{Education}

\vspace{\baselineskip}

\begin{tabular}{rl}
\textsc{4.0 GPA} & \textbf{Undergraduate} \\ 
                 & \textsc{Natural Sciences} \\ 
                 & \textit{University of California, Berkeley}
\end{tabular}

\vspace{\baselineskip}

\section{Classes Taken}

\vspace{\baselineskip}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Congrats on the GPA :) -- Next time please include the `\documentclass`, `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`.

Comment: @AndrewCashner Wow I'm so sorry I was sure to have provided a complete MWE. I've just copied and pasted the code. I don't know what happened! Anyway, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

**1.** if you are not going to insert contents between `\section{}` and `tabular` (I mean, if the `tabular` is the first non empty line) you don't need `\noindent`.

Otherwise, the second paragraph (the `tabular`) will be indented and you have to remove it using `\noindent`.

**2.** As cited by @Andrew Cashner, you have to remove the empty space at the beginning of the cell making use of `{@{}rl}`.

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{report}  

\begin{document}

\section{Education}

First line here without \verb|\noindent|

\vspace{\baselineskip}

%   \noindent
    \begin{tabular}{@{}rl}
        \textsc{4.0 GPA} & \textbf{Undergraduate} \\ 
        & \textsc{Natural Sciences} \\ 
        & \textit{University of California, Berkeley}
    \end{tabular}

\section{Education}

First line here with \verb|\noindent|

\vspace{\baselineskip}

\noindent %
\begin{tabular}{@{}rl}
    \textsc{4.0 GPA} & \textbf{Undergraduate} \\ 
    & \textsc{Natural Sciences} \\ 
    & \textit{University of California, Berkeley}
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

Comment: It's only the `@{}` setting, not the alignment, that causes the problem.

Comment: @AndrewCashner, you are right. I edited. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The tabular environment by default inserts a small amount of horizontal space to the left of the first column. You can control the space between columns with the argument of `@{}` in the `tabular` preamble. Putting nothing there removes the space and solves your problem.

```
\begin{tabular}{@{}rl}
\textsc{4.0 GPA} & \textbf{Undergraduate} \\ 
                 & \textsc{Natural Sciences} \\ 
                 & \textit{University of California, Berkeley}
\end{tabular}
```